# Why do people use AWS over Docker Containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, open-source

AWS provides services like Elasticache, redis, databases and all are charged on hourly basis. But these services are also available in form of docker containers in docker hub. All the AWS services liste above use an instance. Meaning, an independent instance for databases and all. But what if one starts using an ec2 instance, and start downloading all the images for all the dependancies on databases. That would save them a lot of money right?

I have used docker before and it has almost all the images for the services aws provides.

Answer (score 1):

**EC2 is not free.**  You can run, for example, MySQL on an EC2 instance.  It will be cheaper than using RDS, but you still need to pay for the compute and storage resources it consumes.  Even if you run a database on a larger shared EC2 instance you need to account for its storage and CPU cycles, and you might need more or larger instances to run more tasks there.

(As of right now, in the us-east-1 region, a MySQL db.m5.large instance is US$0.171 per hour or US$895 per year paid up front, plus US$0.115 per GB of capacity per month; the same m5.large EC2 instance is US$0.096 per hour or US$501 per year, and storage is US$0.10 per GB per month.  [Assuming 1-year, all-up-front, non-convertible reserved instances.])

**There are good reasons to run databases not-in-Docker.**  Particularly in a microservice environment, application Docker containers are stateless, replicated, update their images routinely, can be freely deleted, and can be moved across hosts (by deleting and recreating them somewhere else).  (In Kubernetes/EKS, look at how a Deployment object works.)  None of these are true of databases, which are all about keeping state, cannot be deleted, cannot be moved (the data has to come with), and *must* be backed up.

**RDS has some useful features.**  You can change the size of your database instance with some downtime, but no data loss.  AWS will keep managed snapshots for you, and it's straightforward (if slow) to create a new database from a snapshot of your existing database.  Patch updates to the database are automatically applied for you.  You can pay Amazon for these features, in effect, or pay your own DBA to do the same tasks for a database running on an EC2 instance.

None of this is to say you *have* to use RDS, you do in fact save on AWS by running the same software on EC2, and it may or may not be in Docker.  RDS is a reasonable choice in an otherwise all-Docker world though.  The same basic tradeoffs apply to other services like Elasticache (for Redis).